# Why protected internal class cannot derive?

Tags: c#

Scope of the `protected internal` is same assembly, or by any derived class in another assembly.Then Why protected internal class cannot derive?

**Sample code:**

```
 protected internal class AbsClass
    {
        int m = 50;
        public int am = 5;     

        public void nonAbsfn()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m + am);
        }
    }

    class TestAbstract : AbsClass
    {


    }
```

Comment: You **can** derive from a protected internal class. Please show some code.

Comment: A class can only be `protected internal` if it is an inner class. Otherwise, a class can only be `public` or `internal`. The code you show doesn't compile. Please show your real code with the necessary context.

Comment: But scope of the protected internal is within the same assembly..right

Comment: while compiling itself,its throwing error becoz of protected internal

Comment: A class doesn't have a scope. As it stands, your question lacks crucial info and as such makes no sense.

Comment: @P.PrabhakaranB.E - What is the actual compiler error you are getting?

Comment: @P.PrabhakaranB.E what is point of asking this question can you elaborate little with practical case

Comment: @Arun_C_C Elements defined in a namespace cannot be explicitly declared as private, protected, or protected internal

Comment: So that is nothing to do with deriving from the class then. The problem is with the location of your definition of `AbsClass` itself as per Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A class can only be `protected internal` if it is an inner class.
Otherwise, a class can only be `public` or `internal`.

To fix your compilation error, make the class either `public` or `internal`. The error you are getting has nothing to do with the derived class `TestAbstract`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx):

> The type or member can be accessed by any code in the assembly in which it is declared, or from within a derived class in another assembly. Access from another assembly must take place within a class declaration that derives from the class in which the protected internal element is declared, and it must take place through an instance of the derived class type.

So you should be able to do it. Can you post some of your code?